# Can I create a link that takes me to another web page and triggers a javascript action there?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'd like to hyperlink a button on my web page that takes me to another website and clicks on a link there that activates javascript to open a different landing page. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Do you want the Javascript at the target page to always trigger, or just when the page is navigated to from that specific page?

Comment: In contrast to Sachin, no, I don’t think that’s possible. That would be in clear violation of the cross-origin restriction.

Comment: The target page has 3 checkout options that use javascript to navigate the visitor to the appropriate checkout option page. I'd like to link 3 buttons on my own page to go to each of the other page's landing pages respectively. Since they're using javascript to trigger the page options, I don't know how to link to them via HTML. Possible?

Comment: It is possible, the landing page just needs to implement the actual Javascript and trigger it when receiving a specific querystring or somesuch `?triggermyjavascript=yes`

Comment: Do you own/control the other website?  You could write a JS that either looks at the referrer, or a query string, to change the behavior.

Comment: I don't own or control the other website. Is it still possible to create such a trigger from my own website?